# Azure Workbook - Dropdown multiple selection int

Tags: azure, appinsights, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have have setup a parameter of type dropdown to be able to select the log level like this:
[image: Query parameter]

Then I try to use it in my query like this:
[image]

But I have the following error because he is not able to cast it as int apparently.
[image: Error]

After that they are probably some easier option to filter on severtityLevel.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

if the values truly area numbers in the content, in the parameter settings you can change the "quote with" section above in your screenshot to not quote the values when generating the query:

[image: quote with]

you can set "quote with" to be blank, and you'd get

`in (1, 2, 3)` instead of `in ('1', '2', '3')`

the other option is to change your query to do something like `where tostring(severityLevel) in ({level})` so that your column *is* converted to a string before the `in` comparison takes place.